# Is it possible to write a message to the area where the browser shows links, download progress etc.?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I would like to write a small progress message to the bottom left corner of the browser window where browsers show links when hovering, or waiting for data etc. See image below for a better explanation.

[image]

i.e. I would like to write to the grey part in the attached picture which is currently showing the link 'opensource.org/licences/MIT'. It needs to be generic method, e.g. works in Chrome, FF, IE, but happy if its only in modern, HTML5 browsers.

Comment: Sorry. I did look but didn't know it was called the status bar. I tried to delete the question, but it wouldn't let me. Please delete if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make div like this to show message and give css like this

```
.message {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size:14px;
    background: #CCC;
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Since most browser don't allow to modify the status bar from JavaScript in a web page, this is probably the best workaround.

Comment: I'm glad you like this idea. @AaronDigulla